# В чём ошибка в Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Делаю приложение Windows Form на C# в Visual Studio. Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Антидурительная_игра
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static Form form1 = new Form1();

        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            form1 = new Form1();
            Application.Run(form1);
        }
    }
}
```

Появляется это окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, я тупой. Но плиз, подскажите, что делать

Comment: Уберите `new Form1()` из определения поля.

Comment: капец спс)) чё то я затупил

Answer (score 1):

public static Form form1 = new Form1();
Удаляйте = new Form1() и все будет ок (^_^);